# Closure of the image of an annulus under a non-polynomial entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an entire function. How can one show that if $f$ is not a polynomial, then $\overline{f(A)}=\mathbb{C}$, where $A$ is the annulus $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|>r\},\forall r>0$?

If $f$ is a polynomial, then the funtion $g:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, given by $z\mapsto g(z)=f(1/z)$, has a pole at $z=0$ (and vice-versa). Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Suppose $f(A)$ is not dense. Then there exists an open disk $B(w,s)$ disjoint from $f(A)$. Note that $|\frac  1{f(z)-w}| \leq \frac 1  s$ for $|z| >r$. Let $z_1,z_2,...,z_n$ be the zeros of $f(z)-w$ in $\{z:|z| \leq r\}$ counted according to multiplicities. Let $g(z)=\frac {\prod_j (z-z_j)} {f(z)-w}$. Then $g$ is an entire function and there exists  a finite constants $C,D$ such that $|g(z)| \leq C|z|^{n}+D$. This implies that $g$ is a polynomial of degree at  most $n$. Can you finish?

Comment: I do not understand why $g$ is an entire function. Is it 
necessarily well-defined at $z=z_1,\ldots z_n$?

Comment: It has removable singularities at the points $z_i$. The numeartor cancels out the zeros of the denominator to eliminate the poles. @user52305

Comment: So, if $m\leq n$ is the degree of $g$, then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-m$, which contradicts the initial assumption.

Comment: Don't  look at degrees. Once you know that $g$ is a  polynomial observe that $f$ is a rational function. But we already know that $f$ is entire so it must be a polynomial. @user52305

Comment: Ok. Also, why are there finite constants $C$ and $D$ such that $|g(z)|\leq C|z|^n+D$? (I'm not familiar with entire functions.)

Comment: For $|z| >r$ $|f(z)-w| \geq s$ and the numerator in $g(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. For $|z| \leq r$, $g$ is bounded by continuity.  @user52305